# How does AirDroid's web.airdroid.com get routed to my device?

Tags: android, networking

I am using AirDroid ([PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid)). When you start the app in your home network you can reach you Android device by the URL: http://web.android.com. But how does the device tell my wireless router to route this URL to the Android device?

Comment: and how does it possibly distinguish between multiple devices running Airdroid on the same subnet? I'm afraid, however, these question are not really suited for SO.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but I assume the app gets the device's local ip address, sends it to the airdroid servers, which send it back to the webapp running in the browser on your desktop. Then the webbapp probably uses the ip and ajax or websockets to connect to a webserver running in the airdroid app on the device.

Answer (score 0):

When you log in to your Airdroid web app in your browser and also in your phone it has the information stored about your network so when you try to connect to the mobile device by the browser it checks if the IP is of the same network it connects in local mode otherwise if you are on mobile data or in other network it goes by the airdroid server to reach to the device